# Problem with scanning many integers in a row

Tags: arrays, c, memory, scanf, stdin

When trying to read about 2000 int numbers, scanf() stops working after 1040 ints. How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int length;
    scanf("%d", &length);

    int32_t *array = (int32_t *) calloc(length, sizeof(int32_t));

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("\nAll data are scanned\n");

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you providing the data to your program? Typing each value? copy/paste? Redirect from file? What platform are you running this on?

Comment: copy/paste the data

Comment: Is the data you copy-paste 100% correct? Are you ***really*** sure about it, and that there's no invalid character in the text? It's only digits and spaces? No decimal (floating point) numbers? No letter? Nothing invalid?

Comment: As a simple way to check that the input is valid, read line by line instead (using e.g. `fgets`) and then use `sscanf` (for example) to parse the string into a number. If `sscanf` fails (which you check using its [return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)) then report it together with the actual input (what `fgets` gave you) to make sure it's valid. In fact, I really recommend you kind of forget that plain `scanf` (and even `fscanf`) exists, and only read lines and other ways to parse each line.

Comment: You have not checked the return value from `scanf` which should be `1` (here). Never omit to do that.

Comment: Copy/paste? Do you mean piping to `stdin` from the clipboard?

Comment: I would guess you may be running into a limitation of the input buffer. I would suggest redirecting from a file or modifying your program to read from a file using `fscanf`.

Comment: By the way, do the input you paste have newlines in it, or is all the data only space or tab delimited? Perhaps if you add newlines into the data to flush the buffers and actually send the input to the program it could work (regarding the commend by @RetiredNinja).

Comment: When I copy/paste into a program like that, on my machine there's a limit of only about 1kb on how much data there can be per line.  So I second the suggestions of Retired Ninja and Some Programmer Dude.